# Is there a keyboard shortcut to highlight the selected text in MS Word 2007?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word

I have done a bit of searching and cannot find a keyboard shortcut for this command in Microsoft Word 2007.  **I am not talking about simply making a text selection.** (that would be a no brainer)  What I would like to do is select some text and toggle the background color so it appears as if it were marked with a yellow highlighter.

Is there any way to do this with a keyboard shortcut?

[image: Highlight Color Command Button]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can set them in Word Options, Customize, Keyboard Shortcuts.

**Edit:** Actually, it's already <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.

Comment: @Daniel - awesome!  May I ask where you found the answer?

Comment: I delved into the customize keyboard short cuts and looked for Highlight under all commands.

Comment: In windows there was a way to display all the shortcuts in the word window itself on all the options. For Mac ?? any idea

Comment: what about mac?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create your own macros for that, using the Word Macro recorder.

1. highlight a word or phrase
2. Start the macro recorder (Tools - Macro - Record new macro)
3. assign the macro a name, define if it should be stored in Normal.dot or the current file, assign a keyboard shortcut (after all this, you'll close the dialogs and end up with a recording icon)
4. format your selected text
5. Stop the macro recorder

Comment: This is a good solution for Word Mac version.

Answer (score 2):

You can set them in Word Options, Customize, Keyboard Shortcuts.

Goto "Tools" menu and select "Highlight" option

Assign keyboard shortcut to it like "Ctrl+H"

Answer (score 0):

First, you make sure you have the right color. Then highlight with your curser and press. Ctrl+ alt + H . After that, you can just highlight it with your cursor and tapped «Ctrl + alt + H ».

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to select the color to start with and then keep using that color with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> till the time you need to change the color.